# Vue JS - Reactivity $set property of property in an object array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My Vue.js version is v1.0.28. I was wondering how I could use `Vue.$set` to set a deep property of an object array. For example, I have:

```
this.pairs = [
    {
        "left_media": {
            "name": "A",
            "show": false
        },
        "right_media": {
            "name": "B",
            "show": false
        }
    },
    {
        "left_media": {
            "name": "B",
            "show": false
        },
        "right_media": {
            "name": "A",
            "show": false
        }
    }
]
```

I need to loop through `this.pairs` array and update the `show` property of each media `name == A` to `true`.

I can seem to update them easily via a for loop, but the view won't change. I've done some research and seems like `Vue.$set` can help fix this, but I can't seem to get it work in this case.

How do I use `$set` to do: `this.pairs[i].left_media.show = false;`?

**EDIT**

AJAX call to update `show_comment`

```
toggleComment: function(media, which_media) {
  this.$http.post('/api/project-media/update.json', {
    id: media.id,
    show_comment: !media.show_comment
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.body.success) {
      // update show_comment status for this media in all pairs\
      for (let pair of this.pairs) {
        for (let key of Object.keys(pair)) {
          if (key == 'project_media_left' || key == 'project_media_right') {
            if (pair[key].id == media.id) {
              this.$set(pair[key], 'show_comment', !media.show_comment);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, function (response) {
  });
}
```

Comment: How are you adding items to `pairs`?

Comment: Ah, the array is pulled from the DB :)

Comment: So, how specifically is the data from the database added to pairs?

Comment: Data from the sever side has been formatted and passed down to the client side, I brought it over using PHP `json_encode` i.e. `var pairs = <?= json_encode($pairs, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;`

Comment: Do any of the options in the answer work for you? If not I guess we need to see more code.

Answer (score 1):

If your target environment supports [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or you are using babel or something to compile, then its just

```
for (let pair of this.pairs)
  for (let v of Object.values(pair))
    if ('A' == v.name) v.show = true
```

If not then

```
for (let pair of this.pairs)
  for (let key of Object.keys(pair))
    if (pair[key].name == 'A')
      this.$set(pair[key], 'show', true)
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YQKjMB?editors=1010).

But to be honest,

```
for (let pair of this.pairs)
  for (let key of Object.keys(pair))
    if (pair[key].name == prop)
      pair[key].show = true
```

also works for me, so I wonder if there is something else going on with your issue.

Comment: I've tried your solutions. A couple of issues though:

The method using $set reports an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.trim is not a function(…)`. Perhaps it's not setting the right property?

The other methods do successfully change the value of the media, but the change is not showing on the browser.

Comment: @nogias Can you post the code where you are doing the update? Sounds like it is in an Ajax callback.

Comment: You are right, there's an AJAX call. I've updated the question above, sorry it's a bit different from my simplified example above but the idea is the same.

Comment: @nogias Where is this different from yours? This appears to work. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YQKjMB?editors=1010

Comment: Just checked, yeah no difference, although using `$set` always throws me an error `t.trim is not a function...`. It's getting strange.

Comment: @nogias Version issue maybe?

Comment: My Vue.js version is  v1.0.28, maybe this is why?

Comment: @nogias could very well be. My example is in v2.